# PHPmailer with AWS SES

Tags: php

I am trying to send emails through PHPmailer using the AWS SES SMTP account.

Somehow it sends emails when I ping the file from the terminal but fails to do so when I hit the same file from the browser. Below is the code.

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->setFrom($sender, 'xx@site.com');
$mail->Username   = USERNAME;
$mail->Password   = PASSWORD;
$mail->Host       = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 4;                                                                                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->addAddress('xx@gmail.com');
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->Body       = $bodyHtml;
$mail->AltBody    = $bodyText;
$mail->Send();
```

The error in the browser says: `SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host`.

Comment: How are you hitting the file in your browser?

Comment: using a direct link to the file. e.g. site.com/filename

Comment: SMTPDebug must have printed what went wrong while connecting the SMTP server. Use debug level 2 in case 4 is very verbose.

Comment: Have you checked whether any PHP settings differ between CLI and webserver usage?

Comment: I did that and it returned the below error;

Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`cp.xx.com' did not match expected CN=`email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'

Both are same